# DNS records to redirect everything to another domain

Tags: dns, alias, cloudflare, wildcard-subdomain

I have several domains:

- example.co
- example.io
- example.com

I want to redirect everything from .co and .io to their counterparts in .com, which means:

- sub.example.co => sub.example.com
- api.example.io => api.example.com
- example.co => example.com
- ...

I've heard about `DNAME` records, but cloudflare do not support them.

Answer (score 0):

If you just mean normal url forwarding, according to [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules) link, you just have to:

1. Log into your Cloudflare account.
2. Click the appropriate Cloudflare account for the domain where you want to add URL forwarding.
3. Click the Page Rules app.
4. Under Page Rules, click Create Page Rule. The Create Page Rule for  dialog opens.
5. Under If the URL matches, enter the URL or URL pattern that should match the rule. Learn more about wildcard matching.
6. Next, click Add a Setting.
7. Choose Forwarding URL from the drop down menu.
8. Click Select Status Code and choose 301 (Permanent Redirect) or 302 (Temporary Redirect).
9. Enter the destination URL.
10. To finish, click Save and Deploy.

Hope I could help, if not, the page contains some other interesting solutions under the Advanced Forwarding Options, such as using variables.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I went through this option already... unfortunately this only works for http

Answer (score 0):

Page Rules are great and will help to route the traffic as you want. There is a good tutorial with examples here, https://community.cloudflare.com/t/using-page-rules-to-perform-redirects/55386. In particular, the section about using variables will be particularly useful for what you want to accomplish.

If you have questions are you work through the rules, let us know at the Cloudflare Community, Community Tip - Welcome stackoverflow Visitors, https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-welcome-stackoverflow-visitors/99529

+1 to "Page Rules works with both HTTP and HTTPS" from Faiz! That is correct. This statement is not accurate -> "unfortunately page rules only works with http".

Comment: thanks for your contribution, but this is the same suggestion as above, and as replied, unfortunately page rules only works with http

Comment: Page Rules works with both HTTP and HTTPS scheme. You can use wildcard (*) to match both protocols. The domain/subdomains must be orange-clouded for Page Rules to work.